# How to reset IBM WebSphere Portal Server

Tags: websphere-portal

While doing some R&D I messed up my IBM WebSphere portal Login page. I appended a custom portlet on Login page along with original Login portlet. Now the Login page is not showing up and I am unable to access Administrative tools. I cannot even revert back these changes now. I have tried writing username and password in URL but no success. Is there any other way/workaround to revert back these changes or reset portal server to original form? because last thing I want to do is a re installation. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I am using IBM WebSphere Portal Server v7

Comment: The answer below applies to v7 and 8 as well! Redbooks just don't get updated for every single release. You can search the portal wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the whole portal with the `ExportRelease.xml` using the `xmlAccess` interface.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/P61t4d

After doing the export you have got the whole page_structure.

You have to search for the login page. I think the parameter was named active. Its likely false.

Try `active="true"`. The login page is named `wps.Login`or something like that.

After modifying the page structure you can run it as a script with [xmlAccess](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Working_with_the_XML_configuration_interface_wp7) as well.

Comment: -1 as this doesn't answer the question. The question asks whether it is possible to restore the WebSphere Portal instance to its original form.

Comment: @Isaac The question was for a reset or reverting the changes. When the login page isn't showing its very likely disabled and enabling it would solve the problem. The asker didn't want to reinstall the portal....

Comment: Your answer neither "resets" Portal Server, nor "reverts" it in a way that would answer the asker's requirement. The asker appended another portlet to the login page, rendering it unusable. From the asker's description, it's quite a leap to determine that the problem stems from the page being inactive. I suggest you edit your response (and get your +1 back, as this appears to have pissed you off).

Comment: Hopefully Umer has long moved past this but I belive Isaac's answer has merit. Umer seems to have two login portlets that are conflicting because both are active. Isaac suggests setting Umer's custom portlet to inactive and activating the original login portlet then importing the changes with xmlAccess; I believe this should revert the changes and satisfies the original question, the spirit of which is essentially 'how do I modify portlet settings when the UI is not available'. xmlAccess is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere Portal 7.0 doesn't provide with a way to "reset" the Portal Server instance to its original, out-of-the-box state. Unlike WebSphere Application Server, where you can simply delete a profile & recreate a new one, this isn't possible with WebSphere Portal.

Having said that, WebSphere Portal 7.0 has the ability to support multiple profiles: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+7+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Supporting_multiple_profiles_wp7&content=pdcontent

So, what you can do is this:

1. Reinstall WebSphere Portal 7.0.
2. Take a backup of the WebSphere Portal 7.0 instance, as per the documentation.
3. When there comes the time to revert to the original, restore from the backup.

That is the only definitive way to reset a WebSphere Portal 7.0 instance... unfortunately.

Comment: "because last thing I want to do is a re installation.", Did you miss that part?

Comment: No. I understand that this is the last thing you want to do. I sympathize with the asker's unwillingness to reinstall Portal Server, as we all know it's not of the most pleasant experiences. But if you read my answer, you'll realize that I provided him with a method to avoid having to reinstall Portal Server next time such a things happens.

Answer (score 0):

Get the XML of the page from other portal environment and import it.